# Toggle 'Paste Remembers Layers'?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I've come across a script for InDesign that toggles on the 'Paste Remembers Layers' menu item.

I would LOVE a visual toggle as I use this all the time but for now this will do (unless anyone knows of something similar/better)

The issue is it only switches it ON. I would love to assign a keyboard shortcut to toggle it between ON/OFF or one for each, etc.

Can anyone tweak this for me or have any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance

```
    // toggle "Paste Remembers Layers"
var rem_paste_lay = app.menuActions.item('$ID/Set Paste Remembers');
var bk = rem_paste_lay.checked;
if (bk == true) {
  rem_paste_lay.invoke(); // if true toggle to false
};


// restore
if (rem_paste_lay.checked !== bk) {
  rem_paste_lay.invoke(); // if not eq bk toggle 
};
```

Comment: It is all there, assuming it works. If you remove everything except lines `2` and `5` it should toggle. If you want some indicator for the state, you can keep line `3` and add this at bottom `alert('Paste Remembers Layers \n' + bk ? 'unchecked' ? 'checked' );`. An alert window should pop up after every toggle that gives you the current state. — I did not test any of this.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not very good with scripting, I'm a designer so this is all foreign to me.. 

I now have this but it's not working:

// toggle "Paste Remembers Layers"
var rem_paste_lay = app.menuActions.item('$ID/Set Paste Remembers');
  rem_paste_lay.invoke(); // if true toggle to false
};

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm probably missing something. I'm not aware of this option. Which INDD version and where is the setting located?

Comment: It's version 16.1 
The setting is in the layers panel menu dropdown

Comment: It seems to work fine for me, except that I'm noticing that it doesn't work without a document open. When you don't have a document open, the script says the state of this option gets toggled, but the menu item doesn't change visibly. Could that have been the issue? 
[`var rem_paste_lay = app.menuActions.item('$ID/Set Paste Remembers'); rem_paste_lay.invoke(); alert('Paste Remembers Layers: \n' + (rem_paste_lay.checked ? 'ON' : 'OFF') );`](https://pastebin.com/85UuSFDU)

Comment: And by the way, you probably don't care, but I changed the alert popup from my original suggestion to say "ON" or "OFF" because my dyslexia was firing on all cylinders while testing it and I couldn't always tell the difference between the states because the word "checked" was so dominant.

Answer (score 1):

Did some prelim searching for a better solution and found this post, in case anyone wants an alternate solution I use a workaround at work to avoid scripting (is this the right crowd for that? :)).

 It's not ideal but you can create **2 custom Toggle on / Toggle off actions:**

1. Create a new action (Windows > Actions > ---ActionPanelMenu > New Action...)

2. Once the new action (**Action 1**) is recording:

3. Navigate to Layers to toggle/ check "Paste Remember Layers"
 (---LayersPanelMenu > Past Remember Layers)

4. > Stop recording (Square stop icon on the Actions panel)

5. Repeat 1-3 for **Action 2**, but this time toggle / uncheck Paste Remember Layers

6. > Stop recording

 You should have 2 actions, I named them and gave them a keyboard shortcut:

Action 1 = PasteRememberLayers ON (I assigned F10)

Action 2 = PasteRememberLayers OFF (I assigned Ctrl+F10)

Unfortunately Illustrator still doesn't have conditionals to do this with 1 action... Hope that helps!

[image: Illustrator Actions Toggle Paste Remember Layers]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!